# Recoloring tree problem. How to recolor minimum number of vertices?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

Graph problem.

There is a tree. Each vertex can be of two colors: red or blue. I can recolor red vertex into blue.
I need to color tree in such a way, that:

1. Number of red colors must be maximum
2. Nearby vertices can not be red. One of them must be recolored to blue.

Tree can have up to 50000 vertices.

What algorithm or idea can be applied here?
I need to find out maximum number of red vertices.

Comment: https://i121.fastpic.org/big/2023/0221/8f/d7c4402309f6521772466a83e5a0b88f.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the nodes of the tree ordered by depth, starting with those furthest from the root. For each node, if it is red and either of its children (if it has any) are red, flip its color. Once this process is complete, iterate over all the nodes, counting the red ones. Overall, this will be `O(n)` time.

On the note of optimality- take an optimal solution, if it does not follow the above rules, there will exist a red subtree in the original tree where one of the leaves is converted to blue. We could instead color its parent blue (since there's no restriction on blue nodes), if its not already blue, and leave the leaf red (since its parent is blue, and by being a leaf in this red subtree, it has no red children). This results as many or more red nodes, making this solution also optimal. Rinse and repeat as necessary, until we arrive at the above result.

Edit: To clarify from the comments, you can order the nodes by doing a BFS from the root and pushing the nodes onto a stack as you traverse them. The stack will then be ordered in non-increasing depth. Note that that requires O(n) space. You can also avoid iterating over the nodes a second time by just counting the red nodes you do NOT flip to blue while iterating. Either way, the time complexity remains the same.

Comment: Don't you count the time taken to sort the the nodes into depth order?  Then you iterate over the nodes twice.

Comment: @ravenspoint I don't sort them-  its a tree, so its already ordered by depth. The repeated iteration is just a constant factor, so its still O(n)

Comment: I do not think a graph that happens to be a tree will necessarily have the nodes ordered by depth - they could be ordered alphabetically by label, or in order they were input, or utterly random